# Rewrite long xor statement

Tags: system-verilog, hdl

Look at the following statement. `c_r` gets assigned an xor versioned of all `c[k]`.

```
always_ff @ (posedge clk_i)
begin
  for(k = 0; k < 16; k++)
    c_r[k*8 +: 8] <= c[k][0] ^ c[k][1] ^ c[k][2] ^ c[k][3] ^ c[k][4] ^ c[k][5] ^ c[k][6] ^ c[k][7] ^ c[k][8] ^ c[k][9] ^ c[k][10] ^ c[k][11] ^ c[k][12] ^ c[k][13] ^ c[k][14] ^ c[k][15];
end
```

The design works, however is there a possibility to refactor the statement for easier maintenance and readability?

<sub>Note: `c` is defined as `logic [7:0] c[16][16];`</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose the following:

```
logic [16*8-1:0] c_r, next_c_r;
logic [7:0] c[16][16];

always_comb begin
  next_c_r = '0;
  foreach(c[idx0,idx1]) begin
    next_c_r[idx0*8 +: 8] ^= c[idx0][idx1];
  end
end

always_ff @ (posedge clk_i)
begin
  c_r <= next_c_r;
end
```

The `foreach` will iterate through all selected indexes. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 12.7.3 *The foreach-loop* for full syntax usage and functionality. `^=` is a binary bitwise assignment operators, refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 11.4 *Operator descriptions*. There are various code examples for `foreach` and `^=` throughout the [LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html).

Comment: Not related to the question, so I will leave this as a comment: I prefer keeping my sequential logic as simple assignments. This way all the code for calculations are group together. I find this helps with code readability as i don't have to jump to another always block to see final calculation. Having an `next_*` is a tittle more typing but well worth it when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a `for` loop inside to compute the XOR result and assign that to the `c_r` slice:

```
  always_ff @ (posedge clk_i)
  begin
    for(int k = 0; k < 16; k++) begin
      logic [7:0] xor_result;
      for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        xor_result ^= c[k][i];
      c_r[k*8 +: 8] <= xor_result;
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure how well this will synthesize with your tool, but I've seen my colleagues use these kind of tricks (in VHDL) all the time.

Comment: This solution achieves the goal of easier maintenance, because c[k][0] to c[k][15] are not listed out manually so it is easier to change the number "16" in the future, if need be.  However, I think some synthesis tools won't know how to best rearrange the chain of xors to reduce logic depth, whereas with a reduction-xor operator the tool has more flexibility in choosing the xor topology.  In these types of scenarios in the past, I've used a loop to rearrange the array indices in such a way that a reduction operator can be used.

Comment: @Morgan It's in section 11.3 Operators of the IEEE 1800-2012 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Reduction operators are useful for this, a short example:

```
wire result;
wire [3:0] bus;

//assign result = bus[0] ^ bus[1] ^ bus[2] ^ bus[3];
assign result = ^bus;
```

So the unary `^` collapses the bus to a single bit, this also works for `&` and `|`.

In your case I believe that this should work:

```
always_ff @ (posedge clk_i)
begin
  for(k = 0; k < 16; k++)
    c_r[k*8 +: 8] <= ^c[k];
end
```

If this is not possible embedding a second loop (which is extracted to a combinatorial section):

```
logic [15:0] parity_bus;

always_comb begin
  for(k = 0; k < 16; k++) begin
  parity_bus[k] = 1'b0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) begin
      parity_bus[k] = parity_bus[k] ^c[k][i];
    end
  end
end

always_ff @ (posedge clk_i) begin     
  for(k = 0; k < 16; k++) begin
    c_r[k*8 +: 8] <= parity_bus[k];
  end
end
```

You are effectively describing 16 sets of XOR logic in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, this does not work yet. `c` is defined as `logic [7:0] c[16][16];`. With the proposed solutio, I get following error message: `Error-[IMEMCT] Invalid memory usage
design.sv, 17
  Memory or memory slice is not permitted to be used in following contexts:
    1. conditional expression in if/case/while statements and so on
    2. source or target expression of assignment statements
    3. operand of equality operator
  Expression : (^c[k])`

Comment: How would such a loop look like? I'm confused because it would be something like `c_xor[k] = c_xor[k] ^ c[k][l]` right?

Comment: We are not here for the easy things ;-). I don't understand the inner loop. Wouldn't that be a combinatorial loop?

Comment: Yes. That would be one possibility. However, I think it would not improve the readability.